# HTTP Request using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: php, ios, http-post, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation

Hi I'm new with AFNetworking 2.0 and I need to connect in my php file using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager but if I get the response it's only returning null.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setObject:contactName forKey:kContactNameKey];
    [parameters setObject:mailTo forKey:kMailToKey];
    [parameters setObject:mailCc forKey:kMailCcKey];
    [parameters setObject:category forKey:kCategoryKey];


    [manager POST:@"http://www.sample.com/sample/sample.php" parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject){

              NSLog(@"Success %@",responseObject);
    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
              NSLog(@"%@",error);
          }];
```

**btw here's a sample line in my php file**

```
$EmailTo=mosGetParam($_REQUEST, 'mailTo', '');

$EmailCC=mosGetParam($_REQUEST, 'mailCc', '');

$fromName=mosGetParam($_REQUEST, 'fromName', '');

$deviceId=mosGetParam($_REQUEST, 'deviceId', '');

$appVersion=mosGetParam($_REQUEST, 'appVersion', '1.0');

$osVersion=mosGetParam($_REQUEST, 'osVersion', '');
```

I hope you can help me.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to using AFHTTPRequestOperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution and my only problem was this line

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

so I changed it to http

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```

and I'll convert the responseObject to utf8 to get the String of it.

```
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,id responseObject){

              NSString *string = [[NString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
              NSLog(@"Success: %@",string);
    }
```